# How to test connection protocol when call TwitterAPI using PHP? (SPDY or HTTP/1.0, 1.1)

Tags: network-protocols, spdy, http-1.1

From this update of Twitter

https://twittercommunity.com/t/removing-support-for-spdy-protocol-on-twitter/132530

How can I determine connection protocol in my server to know above changes affect my code or not?

My server running CentOS 6.5 and call TwitterAPI by php v5.3.

Please tell me a way to test it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23792880/4159235

My server currently using Openssl v1.0.1, so that command works well.